# SSL Validation option for android developer tools

Tags: java, android, ssl, sdk, certificate

Does someone know where I can find that option? I have looked for it on my phone as well as on the Android SDK but cant find that option anywhere in the developers settings. This option would be really helpful to test some of my apps :)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/63ofO.png

Comment: What version of Android are you using?

Answer (score 2):

If you can't find it, for 4.2+, you can tap on Build Number seven times, under Settings > About. You will get a message "Developer mode has been enabled” and you will find it under System, right above About.